# basic node.js callbacks assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been struggling for awhile with callbacks in general.  I'm trying to go back to the basics to try to understand conceptually and this is what I understand so far (yeah, basic).

```
function RandHash (callback) {
  ds_hash = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1); 
  callback();
}

function CompiledHash (){
  console.log(ds_hash);
}

var ds_hash;
RandHash(Compiled Hash);
```

Will yield the random number.

However, I'm lost as to how to get the "ds_hash" variable returned from the callback.

Seems this would work:

```
var ds_hash;
ds_hash = RandHash(Compiled Hash);
```

It doesn't.  If I try to return the value something like:

```
function CompiledHash (){
  return ds_hash;
}
```

It doesn't do anything.

Please help me with this.  Seems I spend 90% of my time with node in callback debugging.  I've built some decent applications but everything has been handled through the async library because of this mental block I have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error you've made is that `RandHash` hasn't returned anything. There's no `return` statement present in the function, so `var anything = RandHash(alsoAnything)` will always result in `anything` being undefined.

#### Functions are first class variables

Functions can be used just as variables can, and passed round as arguments to functions. This is a powerful feature of javascript and something that you'll need to grok to use callbacks. Think of a function as a defined action, and you're just passing that action around.

Also, callbacks should be used to deal with the completion of a process. So the idea is, you know what is meant to happen after process A, and what it is meant to generate, so you can give process A a callback which will be called once A has terminated. Now the scenario here isn't appropriate for a callback situation. It would be much easier for you to do...

```
function RandHash () {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
}
```

And then get your hash by just calling this function, like so...

```
var hash = RandHash();
```

You also want to be aware of javascripts variable scoping, as you're missing the var keyword when referencing `ds_hash` in the `RandHash` function which means the assignment defaults to global scope. This is probably what is responsible for confusing you, as your assignment of `ds_hash` in `RandHash` will be global and therefore available in `CompiledHash`, meaning some functions will still be able to access the `ds_hash` value despite this not being the correct, or proper way to do this.

#### Assuming you will eventually require asynchronous processing

```
function randHash (callback) {
  var hash = /* do hash calculation */
  callback(hash);
}
function compileHash (hash) {
  /* do something using the hash variable passed to this function */
}

randHash(compileHash);  // pass the compileHash function as the callback
```

You should pass your variables as arguments to the callback. That will deal with your scoping issues hopefully.

Also, small note, functions in javascript should typically be lowercase if they aren't going to be used with the `new` statement (ie, a javascript class).

Comment: You're correct in that the scope is what's at the heart of my confusion. The actual function itself needs to complete however which is why I'm using a callback in the first place.

Comment: Is this a contrived example? As the RandHash is capable of returning it's result without using a callback. Assuming that it will eventually operate asynchronously then you can pass the `callback` to the `RandHash` function, calculate the hash inside `RandHash` and then call `callback(hash_value)`

Comment: Yes, simplified just to work it out.  In reality the call is within a function that needs the ds_hash value throughout the function.  This value is created by a series of API calls in that "RandHash" function that need to execute before the callback.  I suspect there is a simpler way to do without using "NewCompileHash" at all?

Comment: By the sounds of it you have all the information you need to get this working, you just need to study up on javascript fundamentals so you get an idea of what's properly happening with callbacks etc. Have a look [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) for a concise explanation of how to use functions in javascript.

Comment: Yes, you're correct :)  Think the core problem is that I have been looking through node.js specific documentation which isn't that clear - because it's purely JS.  Thanks for the link and push in the right direction.  Got it working by doing it the way I was thinking originally... but your example is better:   function RandHash () {
  for (i=0; i<500000; i++) {
    ds_hash = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1); 
  }
  return ds_hash;
}

Answer (score 3):

To truly understand asynchronous behaviour, you should try it with something that is actually asynchronous, and passing values around, not just a global variable, as that will never work when you move on to asynchronous functions :

```
function RandHash (callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var ds_hash = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1); 
        callback(ds_hash); // execute callback when async operation is done
    }, 300);
}

function CompiledHash(hash){ // pass hash
  console.log(hash);
}

RandHash(function(returned_hash) { // this is the callback function 
    CompiledHash(returned_hash);   // pass along the returned data
});
```

The callback function is executed once the asynchronous function, in this case setTimeout, has completed, and passes the data back as an argument.
The callback argument is just the function that is passes as an argument.

```
// regular function
function doStuff(argument) {
    // where argument can be anything, also a function
}

// you can pass a string
doStuff('string');

// or a function
doStuff(function(argument_returned) {

});

// and passing a function you can execute that function with arguments in the original function
function doStuff(argument) {
     var argument_returned = 'string';
     argument(argument_returned); // executes the passsed function

});
```

Comment: Thank you - between your answer and Lawrence's answer I simplified and understand why I was off base and could simplify it greatly!  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function RandHash (callback) {
  ds_hash = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1); 
  callback(ds_hash);
}

function CompiledHash(ds_hash){
  console.log(ds_hash);
}

var ds_hash;
RandHash(CompiledHash);
```

For callbacks and functions, it's a bit difficult to understand variable scopes, and what you are doing is not really recommended. You can pass parameters into callbacks, and should get passed, but I would suggest building it like this:

```
function RandHash (callback) {
  var ds_hash = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1); 
  callback(ds_hash);
}

function CompiledHash(ds_hash){
  console.log(ds_hash);
}

RandHash(CompiledHash);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple notes:

1. If you want to propagate the result of the `callback` then you need to `return` its output in `RandHash`
2. You don't need `ds_hash` to be a global variable if you're planning on returning it, anyway
3. The line `RandHash(Compiled Hash);` is a syntax error (notice the space in the variable name)

Try this:

```
function RandHash(callback) {
    var ds_hash = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1); 
    return callback(ds_hash);
}

function CompiledHash(ds_hash) {
    console.log(ds_hash);
    return ds_hash;
}

RandHash(CompiledHash);
```

Notice that there are no global variables. The `callback` returns a value and the function that executes the `callback` passes it along.

On a style note, you should only capitalize the names of functions that you intend to use as a constructor.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't know how to properly utilize returns here.  Reason I'm confused is that I don't totally understand why I'm passing this second function as a ... what the F is it?  An object?

Comment: In your example, I don't know why, either :) Typically, you pass a callback because some operation is happening asynchronously (e.g. an Ajax request or basically any I/O in Node). The callback executes when the operation finishes (whenever that is). That doesn't apply in this case, so a callback isn't really needed.

Comment: Yep, I totally get it.  Was lost in my ignorance.  Off to study JS functions

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
function RandHash (callback) {
 var  ds_hash = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1); 
  callback(ds_hash);
}

var CompiledHash = function (ds_hash){
  console.log(ds_hash);
}


RandHash(CompiledHash);
```